# solaris 10 keys how to make them work

Tags: command-prompt, solaris-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I am new on Solaris 10. I am using putty to connect to it. I am more used to linux. I am trying to do somethings in Solaris like backspace, upkey to previous commands executed. some posts suggest that i use Bash. well I dont know how to switch from ksh to bash.

another issue is that i am used to have the whole path on my cmd prompt but here i only have  $

How can I change this for me. I want to use the up arrow key to view my old commands, I want TAB to give me th directories or files in the working directory and I want to see the whole path of the PWD i am in.

Is there a way

Thanks for the help

Syed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
PS1='\w $ ' exec bash --noprofile --rcfile /dev/null
```

Here is what this command is doing:

- `PS1='\w $ '` : set the prompt to show your current directory
- `exec bash`   : substitute the currently running shell by bash
- `--noprofile --rcfile /dev/null` : suppress predefined customizations

Comment: thanks for the reply, i will try that. Can you please tell me what this command means as well so that I know what is it that I running. Thanks

Comment: had an issue but solved it myself ...(was adding a comment so had to add this)